# XCODE IOS memory leak for AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I use ARC.

Here is the method for starting the audio in my code:

.h file:

```
 @property (retain,nonatomic)AVAudioPlayer *myAudio;
```

and .m files

```
-(void)myPlaySound:(NSString *)mySoundFile NumberOfLoops:(int)loopsCount ofType:(NSString     *)fileType
{
    if([myAudio isPlaying])
    {
        [myAudio stop];
    }
    NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                           pathForResource:mySoundFile
                                           ofType:fileType]];

    NSError *error;
    myAudio  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:&error];

    self.theAudio = myAudio;
    myAudio.volume = audioVolume;
    myAudio.numberOfLoops = loopsCount;
    myAudio.currentTime = 0.0;
    [myAudio prepareToPlay];
    if([myAudio play] == NO)
    {
       NSLog(@"error");
    }
}
```

Based on the button press, I play different audio files of different length and bit rate and types.

Its working, but I get memory leak issue.

Comment: i see within 10 sec into running 32 bytes of memory leak.

Comment: interestingly i dont see the memory leak when i test in the ipad. I am not sure which one to believe.